# webpage returning 403 error and not showing the actual page

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have a page on my website ( it's html ) which is named "providers.html". 
in order to remove the .html part from url, I added this code to .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

now the problem is that I have a folder which is named "providers" and contains files related to that page.

now when I go to the url, I get a 403 error because browser loads the folder and not the html page.

I really appreciate if any one can give me some guidance to solve this problem.
thanks

Comment: Do you have any other rules? Is there any in the providers folder?

Comment: Well you can't have a page *and* a folder with the same name in a directory tree, so it wouldn't work here either. Best to rename your providers folder.

Comment: Nevermind - seems I've found a solution. Hope it's right, and that it doesn't introduce any potential issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/$
RewriteRule ([^\.]+) $1.html [NC,L]
```

1. Turned off directory slashes. This part is the most important part. Basically, if a directory exists, it shouldn't add a slash. This way, we can continue checking rules against exact URI input.
2. Added a check to see if the the current request does not end with a slash.

   - If it doesn't, rewrite to the respective HTML file
   - Otherwise, load up the contents of the directory. You'll more than likely want to have another `.htaccess` file in there to prevent listings etc., and only allow access to existing files.
3. **Update:** Removed `^` and `$` from the rule, as I don't believe it is necessary here.